# How can I validate the range 1-99 using a regex?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to validate some user input, to ensure a number entered is in the range of 1-99 inclusive. These must be whole (Integer) values

Preceeding 0 is permitted, but optional

Valid values

1. 1
2. 01
3. 10
4. 99
5. 09

Invalid values

1. 0
2. 007
3. 100
4. 10.5
5. 010

So far I have the following regex that I've worked out : `^0?([1-9][0-9])$`

This allows an optional 0 at the beginning, but isn't 100% correct as `1` is not deemed as valid

Any improvements/suggestions?

Comment: Your regex would also deem 110 to be a valid value.

Comment: number?? 0 is permitted? You cant allow 01. Integers cant start with zero.

Comment: Why is 01 valid and 007 or 010 are not? Either accept leading zeros or don't.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Off the top of my head (not validated)

`^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`

Comment: I think this should be: `^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`.  Otherwise, the ^ is bound only to the first alternative, and the $ to the second.  Then again, I don't specifically know Java regexes.

Comment: Hence the "not validated". I couldn't remember that sort of thing specifically.

Comment: note: ^ and $ are not needed if using the `Matcher.matches()` method, since it attempts to match the whole string...

Answer (score 15):

Here you go:

```
^(\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)$
```

Meaning that you allow either of

1. 1 to 9 or 01 to 09, 11 to 19, 21 to 29, ..., 91 to 99
2. 10, 20, ..., 90

Comment: It looks like no one else thinks backwards :)

Comment: Just to add my two cents we originally had a pattern match for this based on 1-9 : existing pattern was  `\\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0  - ` this worked fine in chrome but not on IE. this current suggestion `^(\\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\$` appears to work on both IT and chrome  given thumbs up to answer

Answer (score 5):

```
^(([0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[1-9])$
```

should work

Answer (score 5):

Why is regex a requirement? It is not ideal for numeric range calculations.

Apache commons has IntegerValidator with the following:

```
isInRange(value, 1, 99)
```

In addition, if you're using Spring, Struts, Wicket, Hibernate, etc., you already have access to a range validator. Don't reinvent the wheel with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 2):

pretty late but this will work.

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like...

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Comment: The leading zero is supposed to be optional.

Comment: I know it is supposed to be optional for this question but this solved my own issue where the leading 0 is mandatory for numbers less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for myself:

```
([1-9][0-9])|(0?[1-9])
```

It checks for 10-99 or 1-9 => 1-99
with one leading zero allowed

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
^([0]?[1-9]{1,2})$
```

The range will be set from `0` to `9` and the `{1,2}` means min digits = 1 and max digits = 2.

It will accept, for example: `0, 00, 01, 11, 45, 99,` etc...
It will not accept, for example: `000, 1.2, 5,4, 3490,` etc...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question correctly. Your regex matches one of OP's invalid values: `0`

Comment: That's right! Thank you for seeing my answer. I've made a correction and now it's ok (edit).

Comment: Now it matches `010`.  It should never match more than two digits.  (The question text is ambiguous on that point, but the examples are not.)

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest possible, I can think of:

`^([1-9][0-9]?)$`

Allows only 1-99 both inclusive.

Comment: This doesn't allow a leading zero, for numbers less than 10.

Comment: @AlanMoore Question says that _Preceeding 0 is permitted, but optional_

Comment: As it is, your regex will match a number that contains a leading zero.  But if you add anchors (or use the `matches()` method), it will not.  And the regex must be anchored, since we're trying to validate the string.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for this valid explanation. I accept that regex must be anchored. Your first comment is misleading and hasty.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the regex should also match `01`, `02`, `03`, etc., in addition to what it matches now.

Answer (score -2):

```
^[0-9]{1,2}$
```

should work too (it'll will match 00 too, hope it's a valid match).

Comment: `00` is NOT in the range 1-99 as required... and it will also match `0`, which is listed as invalid.

Answer (score -6):

```
String d = "11"

if (d.length() <= 2 && d.length() >=1) {
    try {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(d);
        return i <= 99 && i >= 0
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not find it as an requirement in description, though now I see it in title. It seemed funny to go out from regex and have same thing.

Comment: Your test is incorrect anyway; zero should not validate.