# How do I create a regex for this text?

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regex that checks if the text follows this format:

> The first two letters will always be 'AB' than it will be a number
>   between 1-9 than either A or B than a dash ('-') than a bunch of
>   random text followed by a colon (':') and then index position that is
>   A letter and 2 digit number.

So like this:

```
AB8B-ANYLETTERS:H12
```

or

```
AB3B-ANYTHINGCANGOHERE:A77
```

I have done this to check the index position but cannot figure out the text before the colon.

```
"^.*:[A-H]\\d\\d"
```

So the general format is:

```
AB[1-9][A or B]-[ANYCHARACTERS]:[A-Z][01-99]
```

I am using Java.

Comment: Why do you need the index position of the trailing term? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression might validate that:

```
^AB[1-9][AB]-[^:]+:[A-Z][0-9]{2}$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/A7uaV0/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/A7uaV0/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^AB[1-9][AB]-[^:]+:[A-Z][0-9]{2}$";
final String string = "AB8B-ANYLETTERS:H12\n"
     + "AB3B-ANYTHINGCANGOHERE:A77";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### Edit

For `AC` cases, we would try:

```
^AB[1-9][AC]-[^:]+:[A-Z][0-9]{2}$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FBvLaF/1/)

Comment: you can replace `[0-9]` with `\\d`, they do the same thing

Comment: OP asked for `[1-9]` for the first number, and `[01-99]` for the second, which, [modifying from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4013014/1270789) would be `(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])`, I think. BTW, your `regex101` links point to a different example.

Comment: Basically it can be any number at the end so I was just doing /d

Comment: Thanks for the response, just one other question how would I do “or” in a regex? Like for our the fourth character you did A-B but if I wanted to do like A and C can I do [A | C]?